# Calculadora financiera

Tags: javascript

Construí esta función:

```js
// Parametros: Ahorro (capital), Años (tiempo), Porcentaje (interes)
function AhorroFuturo (capital, tiempo, interes){
  var i = 1 + interes
  var ip= interes*100
  var monto = 0
  var t = tiempo*12
    for(var k = 1; k <= t; k++){
      var sub= monto + capital;
      var ai = sub*i;
      monto = ai;
    }
  console.log("Si tu ahorras al mes $"+capital+" con un interes mensual de "+ip+"% a "+tiempo+" meses, tendras un monto final de $"+monto+" pesos.")
  return monto
  }
```

Pero me interesa la parte inversa, donde los parámetros sea el monto a obtener, el tiempo y el interés y me responda con un ahorro fijo mensual que debe aportar el usuario.

Sí alguien tiene idea de cómo resolverlo muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes tener en cuenta que tu código original tal cual tiene algunos errores:

```
// Parametros: Ahorro (capital), Años (tiempo), Porcentaje (interes)
function AhorroFuturo (capital, tiempo, interes){
  var i = 1 + interes
  var ip= interes*100
  var monto = 0
  var t = tiempo*12
    for(var k = 1; k <= t; k++){
      var sub= monto + capital;
      var ai = sub*i;
      monto = ai;
    }
  console.log("Si tu ahorras al mes $"+capital+" con un interes mensual de "+ip+"% a "+tiempo+" meses, tendras un monto final de $"+monto+" pesos.")
  return monto
  }
```

1. Primer **posible** error:

Nunca estas llamando a la función que creaste llamada AhorroFuturo, por lo cual esta nunca se ejecutara y nunca hará ningún calculo, al ejecutar el código de la ventana el resultado no puede ser visualizado ni en pantalla ni en consola, ahora bien, corrigiendo esto, si llamas a la función después de que la creas de esta manera con estos valores por ejemplo:

```
AhorroFuturo(20000,10,15);
```

Obtendrás lo siguiente en consola:

"Si tu ahorras al mes $20000 con un interés mensual de 1500% a 10 meses, tendrás un monto final de $6.659730240674116e+148 pesos."

Como veras el interés mensual es incorrecto ya que yo puse como porcentaje el 15% y me muestra en consola el 1500%, por otro lado esta el tema de los meses, ya que me dices que el tiempo lo recibes en años, y si lo recibes en años pero lo muestras luego como meses.

Diez años no son equivalentes a diez meses, diez años son 120 meses, por lo que hay otro error ahí en la variable que usas para mostrar los meses, también el monto resultante es yo creo que demasiado grande como para ahorrar nada mas 20 000 pesos mensuales durante en nuestro caso 10 años (que si, es cierto que se ahorra por mucho tiempo y ganas ciertos intereses, pero ten en cuenta que este numero es gigantesco es mas o menos un numero de 128 ceros seguidos o algo así segun ví)... debe haber algún error matemático ahí, pero pues para asegurarnos de calcular bien este valor ya necesitaremos una formula matemática, entonces el código pasa de ser el que tenias a este:

```js
function AhorroFuturo (capital, tiempo, interes){

  var i = 1 + interes
  var ip= interes*100
  var monto = 0
  var t = tiempo*12

  for(var k = 1; k <= t; k++){
    var sub= monto + capital;
    var ai = sub*i;
    monto = ai;
  }

  document.write(
       "Si tu ahorras al mes $"+capital+" con un interes mensual de "+interes+"% a " + 
       t+" meses, tendras un monto final de $"+monto+" pesos."
  )

  return monto

}

AhorroFuturo(20000, 10, 15);
```

Ahora si centrándonos en la función que pides realizar, antes de dar alguna respuesta primero me gustaría que tu hicieras el ejercicio dandote yo a ti unas pistas, así no solo entrenamos la lógica un poco, en caso de que en unas horas aún no tengas idea de como realizar esto, responderé a la pregunta con código y lo explicare, ya que ya tengo la respuesta, pero considero importante primero darte las herramientas y tratar de que tu misma realices el código, luego en caso de que no sea posible ahí si dar a conocer el código detrás de este. (En el caso de esta pregunta mas que todo por que no existe evidencia de algun progreso o intento en la creación de esta función)

Bien mirando el problema:

Función para obtener el **monto** después de un **tiempo** con determinados **intereses**

Bien, ahora, nosotros sabemos que el monto depende de dos variables, del tiempo en (meses por ejemplo) y de los intereses (Porcentaje).

Yo supongo que si es un banco, te generara intereses positivos por lo que lo que debes hacer para obtener el monto fijo mensual que se debe pagar para obtener determinado monto de acuerdo a los intereses y el tiempo que se establece es:

1.) Al monto a obtener teniendo en cuenta los intereses restarle SOLO la cantidad total de intereses que se generarían de acuerdo al porcentaje y el tiempo.

2.) Para obtener la cantidad total de intereses que se generarían de acuerdo al porcentaje y el tiempo, obtienes el "X" porcentaje de la cantidad total, y a este resultado lo multiplicas por el tiempo, (en este caso yo use la medida recibiéndola en meses).

3.) Al resultado de restarle al monto total el monto de acuerdo a los intereses que se generarian en X tiempo (En meses), dividirlo en la cantidad de tiempo (Meses).

4.) Obtener el valor absoluto del resultado del paso 3

Esto dará como resultado el monto fijo que se debe guardar en el banco por mes para obtener la cantidad total de dinero del primer atributo de la función.

Almenos eso es lo que entendí que necesitabas... si no es así por favor te pido que especifiques un poco mas la pregunta.

Ahora lo que debes hacer es juntar estas 4 pistas para crear la función.
veamos si te queda igual que la mia :)

La función:

```js
function getMontoTiempo(monto, tiempo, porcentaje){
 
  let montoMensual = Math.abs((monto - (monto * (porcentaje / 100))) / tiempo);
  return montoMensual;
  
}

console.log(getMontoTiempo(150000, 6, 10));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, y bueno mi código no lo pase completo jajaja si menciono que el porcentaje debe ser decimal, es decir .15 para que te de bien, ya lo he copilado en consola y si da bien, y eso desde que creo el formulario el interés tendra valores de entre .0001 a .0999 y se me hace exagerado porque no conozco ningún instrumento financiero que te de el 10% mensual.. jajaja bueno pero igual si tengo que especificar eso... y ya tengo una idea de como hacer el código con tus pistas, lo intentare y lo paso xD! Muchas gracias

Comment: Posdata amiga Monni Sánchez, en caso de que mi respuesta halla sido de ayuda y hallas podido realizar la función con exito, me dices yo pongo la función que hice y la explico para posteriormente que puedas marcar esta pregunta como respondida, para ello debes simplemente clickear el chulo que aparece en mi respuesta después de que la halla editado, de esta manera la persona que te halla dado la respuesta que requerías obtiene ciertos puntos por haberla respondido correctamente.

Comment: Por cierto un gusto ayudarte ;)

Comment: jajaja pues espero te guste mi código, porque creo que ya me salió :) Yo a fuerza quería hacer un ciclo inverso jajajaja pero tu lógica fue mucho más sencilla !

Comment: Seguro que sí me gustará! :3, editare mi respuesta para poner mi función y dar como concluida esta pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
function AportacionesFijas (monto,tiempo,interes){
  var t = tiempo*12
  var ip = interes*100
  var i = (1+interes)*t
  var a = monto - i
  var ahorro = a/t
  console.log("Si tu quieres obtener la cantidad de $"+monto+" en "+t+" meses, tu debes ahorrar $"+ahorro+" pesos al mes con un interes compuesto de "+ip+"%")
  return ahorro
}
```

Comment: Amiga, hay un pequeño error en la parte aritmetica de tu función casí te dio del todo!, pero pues ese desface puede llegar a ser aún mas grande con intereses mas grandes y es bueno pues corregir este error, si deseas puedes analizar el código que se ha cambiado ya que fue editada una parte de tu respuesta, en especifico la variable i, lo demas esta igual, saludos!

Comment: Por cierto te felicito!, solo tuviste ese error aritmetico, el resto está bien.

Comment: Ahh segun veo solo será visible la edición por mi hasta que demas personas la revisen, bueno lo que hice fue este cambio:

Comment: var i = (monto * interes);